# sparql why this query returns no result when 'order by' is added

Tags: sparql

I am querying on the DBpedia sparql endpoint with the following query:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?company ?o { 
    ?company a dbpedia-owl:Agent .  
    ?company <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> ?o .
  }
```

which returns a list of results. But now I want to sort the results so I changed it to:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?company ?o { 
    ?company a dbpedia-owl:Agent .  
    ?company <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> ?o .
  }
order by (?company)
```

And there is no result returned.

Could anyone please explain to me why it is so?

Many thanks!

Comment: Works OK for me with a limit applied. You may be running into a timeout with the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @chrisis Since it worked for OP, you should probably post that as an answer.  Good intuition!

Comment: As @chrisis said, you met the anytime feature of Virtuoso and usually ordering is expensive if the intermediate result is large.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?company ?o { 
    ?company a dbpedia-owl:Agent .  
    ?company <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> ?o .
  }
order by (?o)
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.